# Multi-modules project with Spring Boot Gradle plugin

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependencies, multi-module, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

A Multi-module project has modules with the following dependency: web->core->persistence

I added spring-boot-gradle-plugin to web module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
 }
 apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

As spring-boot-gradle-plugin downloads old hibernate versions, i have duplicates in the persistence module.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k80ov.png)

I tried to override hibernate dependencies in the web module and it's working:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
    //Other dependencies

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVersion}"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:${hibernateValidatorVersion}"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateVersion}"
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k80ov.png)

Why does the plugin download old hibernate version? Is there any possibility to exclude old hibernate versions from spring-boot-gradle-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

First off, consider upgrading your plugin version to 1.5.9.RELEASE which is the current stable version. Also, consider using the Spring data jpa dependency which according to the documentation,

> The spring-boot-starter-data-jpa POM provides a quick way to get
>   started. It provides the following key dependencies:
>
> 1. Hibernate — One of the most popular JPA implementations.
> 2. Spring Data JPA — Makes it easy to implement JPA-based repositories.
> 3. Spring ORMs — Core ORM support from the Spring Framework.
>
> By default, Spring Boot uses Hibernate 5.0.x. However it’s also
>   possible to use 4.3.x or 5.2.x if you wish. Please refer to the
>   Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5.2 samples to see how to do so.

You can find the link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html). It also shows you how to override it to use more current versions in a maven project which isn't much different to what you've done.